# I'm stuck trying to factor $x^2-4$ to $(x-2)(x+2)$

Tags: factoring

I am trying to understand each step in order to get from  $x^2-4$ to $(x-2)(x+2)$
I start from here and got this far...
$x^2-4 =$
$x*x-4 =$
$x*x+x-x-4 =$
$x*x+x-2+2-x-4 =$
$x*x+x-2+2-(x+4) =$

After this I try
$x(x-2)+2-(x+4) =$
and this clearly does not even equal the other factorings. I thought the $x$ could be factored out. I'm confused.

I know I can just insert $a^2-b^2$ into the difference of squares formula like so $(a-b)(a+b)$ but I am practicing factoring. I'm just curious to see each and every step of the factoring.

Comment: Expand $(x+2)(x-2)$ and do it in the other sens.

Comment: Add and subtract $2x$ from $x^2-4$ and then carry on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
x^2-4&=x^2-2x+2x-4\\
&=x(x-2)+2(x-2)\\
&=(x+2)(x-2)
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, recall the general formula $$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b).$$
This can be seen by expanding the RHS, or by writing 
$$a^2-b^2=a^2-ab+ab-b^2=a(a-b)+b(a-b)=(a+b)(a-b).$$
Then, with $a=x$ and $b=2$, we have
$$x^2-4=x^2-2^2=(x+2)(x-2).$$

Comment: I see, but I'm kind of confused why it's different when $b = 1$. In that case you don't have to do $-ab + ab$ you can do $-a -b + a + b$. As in $a^2 -a -b + a + b - b^2$ when $b = 1$.

Comment: @Renoldus I don't see how that's the case. I would factor $x^2-1$ via $$x^2-1=x^2-x+x-1=x(x-1)+(x-1)=(x+1)(x-1),$$ which you can check is the same as what I did above with general $a,b$. But of course, there can be many different ways to factor the same thing.

Comment: I know it works your way with $b=1$ but this way only works when $b=1$ $a^2 -a -b + a + b - b^2$ I think.

Comment: @Renoldus I'm not seeing how that way leads to a factorisation. (Perhaps it does, but I'm not seeing it.) Anyway, no need to obssess over slight differences in the specific method, so long as it works.

Comment: Just my observation. Because I spent time today doing this with b=1 and thought I had the factoring down because of it. It was the source of my blockage.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2-4=x^2+2x-2x-4$$

$$=(x^2+2x) - (2x+4)$$

$$=x(x+2) - 2(x+2)$$

$$(x+2)(x-2).$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x^2 - 4$ can be factored then there exist $a, b \in \Bbb R$ such that

$\quad x^2 - 4 = (x-a) (x-b)$

Now multiplying out the rhs and collecting terms,

$\quad (x-a) (x-b) = x^2 - (a+b)x + ab$

So we need to solve the system of equations

$\tag 1 a + b = 0$
$\tag 2 ab = -4$

From equation $\text{(1)}$ we have

$\quad a = -b$

and plugging that into equation $\text{(2)}$,

$\quad -b^2 = -4$

We have two solutions for $b$.

If $b = 2$ then $a = -2$ and so

$\tag {ANS} x^2 - 4 = (x+2) (x-2)$